# Let $f,g :X \to Y$ be continuous functions and $A \subset X$ such that $f\mid_A = g \mid_A$. Show that $f\mid_{cl(A)} = g\mid_{cl(A)}$.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f,g :X \to Y$ be continuous functions and $A \subset X$ such that $f\mid_A = g \mid_A$. Show that $f\mid_{cl(A)} = g\mid_{cl(A)}$.

If $V \subset Y$ is open, then according to the subspace topology $f\mid_A^{-1} [V] = f^{-1}[V] \cap A$. But by assumption $f^{-1}[V] \cap A  = g^{-1}[V] \cap A$ for any $V \subset Y$ open.

Now since $A \subset cl(A)$ we have that $f^{-1}[V] \cap A \subset f^{-1}[V] \cap cl(A) $ and $g^{-1}[V] \cap A \subset g^{-1}[V] \cap cl(A) $.

Doesn’t this show that $f^{-1}[V] \cap cl(A) =g^{-1} \cap cl(A) $?

Comment: The statement you are trying to prove is wrong. Maybe there should be the assumption that $Y$ is Hausdorff?

Comment: You seem a bit confused. We are already given continuity on the whole of $X$ and the question is not about continuity w.r.t subspace topology.

Comment: I added a supplementary answer to @KaviRamaMurthy showing why it fails without the Hausdorff assumption (or at least some separation assumption, not sure if T1 would do it?)

Comment: @Alan . $T_1$ is not sufficient. Example: Let $X=Y$ be an infinite set with the co-finite topology, i.e. any $V\subsetneqq X$  is closed iff $V$ is finite. Let $p,r\in X$ with $p\ne r$. Let $A=X\setminus \{p,r\}.$ Let $f=id_X$. Let $g|_A=id|_A,$ but let $g(p)=r$ and $g(r)=p$. Observe that $\overline A=X.$

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that $Y$ is Hausdorff, $\{x: f(x)=g(x)\}=(f,g)^{-1}(\Delta)$ where $\Delta =\{(y,y): y \in Y\}$, a closed set when $Y \times Y$ is given the product topology. Since $\{x: f(x)=g(x)\}$ is a closed set which contains $A$ it contains $\overline A$ and we are done.

Comment: $ Delta $ is a subset of $ Y x Y $. $ A $ is a subset of $ X $. In general, $ A $ is not a subset of $ Delta $.

Comment: @RafaelMarazuela  $A$ is a subset of $(f,g)^{-1} (\Delta)$.  $(f,g)^{-1} (\Delta)$ is closed because it is the invergse image of $\Delta$ under the  map $(f,g)$.

Answer (score -1):

First, we suppose that $ X $ and $ Y $ are metric spaces.
Suppose that $ x \in cl(A) $ . There exists a sequence of points on $ A $, $  \{ x_n \}_{n \in N} $ such that

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty } x_n = x $$

We conclude that:

$$ f(x) = \lim_{n \to \infty } f(x_n) = \lim_{n \to \infty } g(x_n) = g(x) $$

So if $ f$ equals $ g $ in $ A $ and both are continous, $ f $ equals $ g $ in the [closure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_(topology)) of $ A $.

I'm thinking about the answer in a general topological space.

Comment: The definition of a topology is very broad. In general the closure may not be definable in terms of sequences (or nets) with unique limits. See my comment to the Q for an example.